# IP Tables allow HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I am setting up a basic Firewall rules for my Laptop but I cant seem to get HTTP and HTTPS, thus using of the Webbrowser to work.

My current rules are like this

```bash
# 1. Delete all existing rules
iptables -F

# 2. Set default chain policies
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP


# 3. Allow outgoing SSH for Ethernet(enp12s0) and Wlan(wlp6s0)

iptables -A INPUT -i wlp6s0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp12s0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT  -o wlp6s0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT  -o enp12s0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# 4. Allow HTTP and HTTPS

iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m state   --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -o wlp6s0 -p tcp   -m multiport --dports 80,443
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m state   --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -o enp12s0 -p tcp   -m multiport --dports 80,443
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -i wlp6s0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -i enp12s0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443
```

How can I allow the HTTP and HTTPS traffic so that I can use my browser again?

Comment: Put the decision at last of the line i.e. `iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlp6s0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT`....make the same change in other rules too..

Comment: What problem do you have with yoru browser ? My guess is DNS, you need to allow DNS (port 53)

Comment: You also need a generic "lo" ACCEPT. "iptables -A INPUT -i lo", similarly for OUTPUT and -o lo.

Comment: Accepting traffic on Port 53 fixed it.
@Doug Smythies Do you have a link so I can read up on that?

Comment: I need "lo" ACCEPT on my main WAN /LAN router / firewall. I've seen the requirement mentioned on other forums. Traffic on lo is at a low rate on my system. I monitored 127.0.0.1 for 8 hours there were" 4 DNS related packets, 8 packets when replies are included, port 53; 112 HTTPS related, port 443; 82 Internet Printing Protocol packets, port 631. All packets were addressed from 127.0.0.1 and to 127.0.0.1. I currently allow "lo" to and from anywhere. I will try "lo" to and from itself only.

Answer (score 1):

Through [bodhi.zazen`s](https://askubuntu.com/users/35795/bodhi-zazen) comment I found the solution.

Setting

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

and allowing Input from a previous established connection with eiter

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

fixes the problem.